# Soft Question - Practical Statistcs: What to learn, why learn it and how?

Tags: prediction

**BEGINNING:**

I want to ask a few soft questions about statistics. I understand that maybe/probably some/all off these questions cannot be answered categorically but I would like to try and get some informed opinions on them anyway. I want to learn some practical statistics and that I could apply to actual problems/data sets (e.g. Forecasting the outcome of a sporting event or election or back-testing/designing some kind of strategy).

**MIDDLE:**

I'm almost finished an undergraduate degree in Mathematics and Economics and I just don't feel equipped to actually do anything particularly impressive/useful/reliable with what I've learnt. I have taken all the usual statistics modules in, for example, Classical Inference, Bayesian Inference, Econometrics (basically a course on regression), Generalized Linear Models and could understand most everything I did to a level that was more than sufficient for exams, but I still don't feel I'd know or be able implement what's most important.

I'd imagine some of these important questions might be:

- What methods/models apply where?
- Why do these methods/models apply here?
- What are the key assumptions you're making?
- Why might they be wrong? What are the consequences if they are wrong?

And then I also have questions like:

- Well what about machine learning/neuro-networks and all these other new/exciting areas? Should I instead be exploring those areas rather than learning something else?
- How much statistics is there?
- How much is useful? How do we know?
- What's up and coming at the forefront of statistics?
- what doesn't look like it will stand the test of time?

Maybe my question might be better phrased as:

1. What's the most useful technique(s)/theories/thing(s) you know?

   - Why?
   - When have you used them/what makes them useful?
   - Ok fair enough. I'm convinced. How can I teach myself? Where do I start?
2. What do you foresee being the major up and coming themes in statistics?

   - If it's too difficult to say, how does one begin to gather an educated opinion on the(se) topic(s)?
   - What about the techniques that we already have? How good are they?
   - What are the great accomplishments of statistics to date?
   - How good are we at predicting things and explaining things through numbers?

**END:**

I have found the amount of statistics available to learn overwhelming. I don't know where to start or why to start anywhere. I'd like to be pointed in the right direction.

Books, articles, websites/tutorials and resources that you think might be pointing me in the right direction would be greatly appreciated, as would any advice more generally on how to frame this problem better or phrase these questions better would

Apologies if this question is poorly phrased and/or long and overwritten. I'm very interested in getting to the bottom of some issues raised above.

And finally apologies if this question/something similar has been asked elsewhere on this site or belongs elsewhere. I had a look around and couldn't find what I was looking for, which is hardly surprising given I'm not quite sure what I'm asking.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Great, difficult question.

Comment: I count 16 questions here.  We're not set up to answer large numbers of questions in individual threads.  Moreover, many of these have been asked before and already have good answers: search our site for them.  After you have done that, you might be able to focus what remains and narrow it down to just a few questions, which you could consider asking separately.  But please review our [help] first, because some of these questions appear to solicit opinions or subjective advice, which doesn't fit our model either.

Comment: These questions have a lot of answers on the whole CV site. I suggest you read the entire website.

Comment: I think if this question has an answer, then it would belittle statistics. There are thousands of different statistics books and techniques, and the question of which method is better is not only vast but opinionated. The answer is: fire up google and look for similar problems from which you can recycle old techniques and invent new ones.